# How do you manually write an Android ListView by hand?

Tags: android

I need to create a very small ListView. Each row could have a different element floated on the right. For example, the top row will have a checkbox and the last row will have a disclosure arrow. It's pretty similar to the ListView that the Settings app has, where each row has a different accessory.

```
Row 1     []
-------------
Row 2    123
-------------
Row 3    abc
-------------
Row 4      >
```

I don't think I can use a ListAdapter because it forces the rows to be homogenous. And since I'm only gong to have 4 rows, I'd rather just manually write the XML for each row. I couldn't find out what the child rows of ListViews are called. On iPhone, the UITableViewCell is the child of UITableView. On Android, I did not find such a ListViewCell or ListViewRow.

Comment: List adapter is the component used to render the individual items in a listview. If you don't want to implement a ListAdapter, then forget about listview. if you want to manually code each row, ListView is not appropriate, and other views are the tools you want. The List adapter does not necessarily force the rows to be homogoneous. Every row will use the same rendering logic, but based on the object represented by the list item, or the ID of the item itself, you can render appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TableLayout..

```
     <TableLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TableRow>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/backbutton"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
           <View
           android:layout_height="2dip"
           android:background="#FF909090" />//this view will help you to draw line so table layout will look like listview

</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="First Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1" />
        <EditText
        android:width="100px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
           <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF909090" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Last Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1" />
        <EditText
        android:width="100px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
            <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF909090" />
</TableRow>
```

Instead of EditText you can use component like checkbox. with the id of corresponding checkbox you can perform process according to you.. I think it may help you..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at TableLayout.  This sounds like what you're looking for:

- http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#tablelayout

You can even wrap it in a ScrollView if necessary.

Also, it is possible to have different views for different rows of a ListView but it seems like a static layout makes more sense given your current needs.

Comment: If you go into the Settings app and choose Display, this is pretty much what I want. Every row has a different accessory on the right edge. Do you think the Settings app uses TableLayout?

Comment: @JoJo If the type and amount of rows you need are dynamic then a ListView is probably better.  ListAdapters have a `getView()` method that you can override to return the specific view for your row's data.

Answer (score 1):

ListAdapter doesn't require the rows to be homogenous. You just implement `getView` to return the view and `getItemViewType` to return a different `int` for each different type of row.

Answer (score 1):

In Android, there are a number of layout elements (Views) that can be nested arbitrarily. Android Views do not necessarily correspond 1 to 1 with IPhone UI elements, but you can certainly get the functionality you want. [Hello Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) is probably where you want to go to familiarize yourself with the Views and layouts that are available.

The layout you're probably looking for is LinearLayout (Vertical). In a linear layout, you can include any other child views, including other layouts you define.

An alternative way of implementing would be to use a custom ListAdapter that switches over the item type being rendered, and selects the appropriate component to use(checkbox, button, image, whatever). However, unless you have some Collection of items you want to render, or a cursor full of those items, Listview is a somewhat unnatural View to use IMO. And while ListView can support non-homogenous items, it is often not the correct tool for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

TableLayout would do the trick, but is kind of like going directly for GridBagLayout in Java..something of overkill.

I've done something very similar with a custom ExpandedListAdapter.  The equivalent thing that would do what you're looking for is to use an ArrayAdapter and override getView. As the javadocs for Android say "To use something other than TextViews for the array display, for instance, ImageViews, or to have some of data besides toString() results fill the views, override getView(int, View, ViewGroup) to return the type of view you want."

The trick I used in my code was to have the view that is inflated vary based on the data and you could do something similar for the right hand content. The view I inflated was a horizontal linear layout with just a few differences that depended on the data type.  Should work well for the use case you describe.

If you are dead set on hand coding the XML layout for the whole thing, which I think will bite you later, then use ListView and ListViewItem elements (see last link below for an example).

Some links to help are:

http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/using-arrayadapter-and-listview-in-android-applications
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

http://danroundhill.com/2009/12/18/working-with-the-android-listview/

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom ListFragment or ListActivity.
Create a custom adapter which can return a view which is populated dynamically depending on the row number of the condition. R>id.list_item could contain a  View which is populated dynamically

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {
private ContactAdapter mAdapter;

public MyFragment() {}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
             getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  

    mAdapter = new ContactAdapter(getActivity(), 
                    R.layout.list_item,R.id.key, contactItemList);
    mAdapter .setInflater(mInflater);
    mAdapter.setLayout(R.layout.list_item);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter );
    }
}
class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactItem> {

   private static String TAG = EfficientAdapter.class.getName();
   private LayoutInflater inflator = null;
   List<ContactItem> pairList = null;
   private int layout;
    public ContactAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, List<ContactItem> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        ….
    }


    /**
     * Make a view to hold each row.
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
     *      android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        return a custom convertView
            ..
     }
 }
```